# Bitshifting and sign

Tags: scala

Let me start with the problem:

```
  def word(byte1 : Byte, byte2 : Byte, byte3 : Byte, byte4: Byte) : Int = {
    ((byte4 << 0)) | ((byte3 << 8)) | ((byte2 << 16)) | ((byte1 << 24))
  }
```

The goal here is pretty simple. Given 4 bytes, pack them in to an `Int`.

The code above does not work because it appears the shift operator tries to preserve the sign. For example, this:

```
word(0xFA.toByte, 0xFB.toByte, 0xFC.toByte, 0xFD.toByte).formatted("%02X")
```

Produces `FFFFFFFD` when I would have expected `FAFBFCFD`.

Making the problem smaller:

```
0xFE.toByte << 8
```

Produces -2 in two's complement, not 0xFE00.

How can I do a shift without the sign issues?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the problem for the ``word`` function? Is it a problem with the current implementation?

Comment: @JeanLogeart the `word` function actually works as I want it to. My question is how can I write it without having to do the `& 0x000000FF` and `& 0x0000FF00`... to strip out the sign funny business.

Comment: Curiously there is a `>>>` operator that sounds like what I want, but no `<<<` operator.

Comment: `>>>` wouldn't do what you want either. The shift would be performed with zero-extension, but the byte would still be converted to an int with sign-extension before the shift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AND the bytes with `0xFF` to undo the effects of sign extension before the shift:

```
((byte4 & 0xFF) << 0) | ((byte3 & 0xFF) << 8) | ...
```

Comment: Ah. That's better than the solution I came up with. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your suspicion is correct and @user2357112 answers your question.

Now, you can use [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) as a clean alternate:

```
def word(byte1 : Byte, byte2 : Byte, byte3 : Byte, byte4: Byte) : Int = 
  ByteBuffer.wrap(Array(byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4)).getInt
```

Comment: Thanks, good to know what can do it out of the box in this scenario.